# Unable to set JWT cookie with spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cookies, jwt

I'm successfully creating a JWT token.
And the login works fine.
But the JWT Token is not sotred in cookies.
At least in my browser, from Postman it seems to work.
Every time I send a POST request to the signin route I get a Header with name Cookie and this Value:

JSESSIONID=*censored*
authToken=*censored*

The authToken does match with my newest generated JWT Token.
But browser side there is no cookie.

This is my spring boot service:

```
    @Override
    public String login(LoginDTO loginDto, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        Optional<UserEntity> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(loginDto.getEmail());

        if (userOptional.isEmpty()) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException(messageSource.getMessage("EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_INVALID", null, myLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(request)));
        }

        try {
            UserEntity user = userOptional.get();

            if (!user.isEnabled()) {
                throw new InvalidRequestException(messageSource.getMessage("EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED", null, myLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(request)));
            }
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getEmail(),
                            loginDto.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            String token = jwtGenerator.generateToken(authentication.getName(), "login");

            Cookie authTokenCookie = new Cookie("authToken", token);
            authTokenCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            authTokenCookie.setPath("/");
            authTokenCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 30); // 30 days

            System.out.println("authTokenCookie Name: " + authTokenCookie.getName());
            System.out.println("authTokenCookie Value: " + authTokenCookie.getValue());

            response.addCookie(authTokenCookie);

            return token;

        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException(messageSource.getMessage("EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_INVALID", null, myLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(request)));
        }
    }
```

My angular code:

```
registerUser(form: NgForm) {
    if (this.email.valid && this.password.valid) {
      const data = {
        email: this.email.value,
        password: this.password.value
      };

      this.isLoading = true;
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/signin', data, {
        headers: {'Accept-Language': this.language},
        responseType: 'json'
      }).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.toastr.success(response.message);
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            this.isLoading = false;
          }, 2500);
        },
        (error: any) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.toastr.error(error.error);
            this.isLoading = false;
          }, 1000);
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

My server log

authTokenCookie Name: authToken
authTokenCookie Name: *censored*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: If you work with CORS you need to enable allowCredentials.
Either with the annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://MY_IP_ADDRESS", allowCredentials = "true")
```

or in the WebMvcConfig

```
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

You'll also have to enable withCredentials in the frontend. This solution is for angular:

```
...
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/...', data, {
    headers: {'Accept-Language': this.language},
    withCredentials: true,
    responseType: 'json'
  }
...
```